# How to display a dummy progress bar from left to right when activity starts in android?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want to make a dummy progress bar that starts from the very left of the screen and ends at the right, at a specified time like 200 milliseconds, how can i make this work?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set your initial and max value for your progress bar. Then, use a Handler to update the progress for your progress bar.

Suppose you want to change your progress bar's progress by click of a button. Your code will look something like this :-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int FRAME_RATE = 10;
    int currentTime = 0;
    int MAX_DURATION = 200;
    int progress = 0;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (currentTime * FRAME_RATE <= MAX_DURATION) {
                progress = ((currentTime * FRAME_RATE) / MAX_DURATION) * maxProgressOfProgressBar;
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                currentTime++;
                handler.postDelayed(this, FRAME_RATE);
            }  
        }
    };
    buttonShowPicNotification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, FRAME_RATE);
        }
    }
}
```

Your code will look something like this.

**NOTE: I have not tested this code but this will definitely give you an idea of what you need to do.**

Comment: I don't understand your code, can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: Code has been updated, please do have a look. If you have any more queries feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a thread which will set the progress every 2 millisecond and finish 100% by 200 milliseconds.

```
        //Class variables
        private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        private int progressBarStatus = 0; 

        //write this code in oncreate after setContentView(..)
        ProgressBar mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (progressBarStatus < 100) {
                // sleeping for 20milliseconds
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                    progressBarStatus++;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mProgress.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: What if the screen was too wide and the progress bar reached status 100 before reaching the right of the screen?

Comment: @EyadMhanna did you tried the above code? Well no matter the size of progress bar the setprogress is in percentage so the fill up of the progress will be done in that regards with the percentage of the width of the progress bar.

Comment: Yes I tried this on a sony device and it works fine but when I run it on a tablet device, the progress bar finishes before reaching the right of the screen.

Comment: Make sure that progress bar width is fill parent
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"

Comment: It is match_parent for sure.

Comment: post your xml layout, as it looks like layout not filled properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97865/discussion-between-eyad-mhanna-and-nikunj-sakhrelia).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html). On every tick update your progress bar and when timer is finish you can do your further next task.
Below is my Activity code:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(SPLASH_TIME_OUT, SPLASH_TIME_OUT / 100) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                progressBar.setProgress((int) (SPLASH_TIME_OUT - millisUntilFinished));
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();
    }
}
```